# is it possible to scan a QR code with the mobile to find a shipment document

Tags: acumatica

Good day

Is it possible to set up my shipments page, on the mobile app, to be able to read a QR code to find the relevant Shipment document?

For example, if I click on the search icon I would like to be able to scan a QR code(on the document) to find the relevant shipment.

version: 20.107.0026

Update: it doesn't have to be a QR code it can be a bar code or a relevant code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device has an integrated / built in barcode scanner (example: A Zebra or Honeywell device) then yes, you can scan a barcode in any of the searches and it will accept the input just as if you have typed it in.
However, if you want to use the camera within the device - that does not work in searches because the camera scanner icon is not present.